# Python Script integration with PowerApps or PowerAutomate

Tags: python, integration, power-automate, powerapps

I have a PowerApps Canvas app in which I need to pull Ldap information. This information is not available using the Get user profile (V2) as it does not pull out specific data. Is there  a way to call a python script in PowerApps canvas app on submit button which will execute the python script and get that inormation from Ldap and update Sharepoint List with the pulled out data?
I was thinking of either doing it in PowerApps canvas app or in PowerAutomate in the flow. I am new to both. appreciate if someone could guide me on what approach will be the best and some guideline on how to go about doing this.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

dont know how to call the python script in either power automate or powerapps.

Comment: You’d need to write an Azure function.

Comment: Just to expand: PowerApp --> Power Automate --> Azure Function   
What kind of data are you needing? Is that data available in [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0&preserve-view=true)?